# How to overwrite sessionId generator in Spring Websockets?

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Is there a way to overwrite the session ID generator that comes with Spring websocket integration? It is always 8 characters (ex: session=imjxvgob), and I would like to generate a longer UUID based session id.

known CVE related to this:
http://pivotal.io/security/cve-2015-0201

JdkIdGenerator class was added to spring-framework 4.2 [Issue: SPR-12658](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/d63cfc8eebc396be009e733a81ebb4c984811f6e), but I don't know how to wire this into my configuration.

I am using SimpleBroker.

**EDIT**
Looks like session id is generated on the client side: socksjs-1.0.3.js:655

```
 var sessionId = options.sessionId || 8;
 if (typeof sessionId === 'function') {
      this._generateSessionId = sessionId;
 } else if (typeof sessionId === 'number') {
 this._generateSessionId = function() {
      return random.string(sessionId);
 };
```

That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a sever generated UUID, and fed that into sockjs library as 'options'.

```
var serverGeneratedSessionId = '${serverGeneratedUUID}'; // new org.springframework.util.JdkIdGenerator().generateId()
var socket = new SockJS('/path', null, {sessionId: function(){
        return serverGeneratedSessionId;
    }});
```